# How do I make a reset button for a simple iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, reset

I am making my first non "hello World app". I have a very simple application that I am making. My app has a date field, some input fields, some switches and a text view. I want to make a reset button that will put the app back to how it was when you first open it.

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     // I will need to use these later 
     @IBOutlet weak var SubmitB: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var DateB: UIDatePicker!
     @IBOutlet weak var ResetB: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var LotI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var BlockI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var EmailI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var BuilderI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var SubdivisionI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var FilingI: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var AddressI: UITextField! 
     @IBOutlet weak var HSSPPP: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var HSUTSLNC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var HSOSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var FFCPPPP: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var FFCFSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var FFCOSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var RGSSPPP: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var RGSOSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var ISSSFR: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var ISFNC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var ISOSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var GSPSSFG: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var GSFGF: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var GSFDNMC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var GSOSC: UISwitch!
     @IBOutlet weak var CommentsI: UITextView!

     @IBAction func ResetBA(_ sender: Any) {
         //this is where I am stuck
     }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you stuck with? What do you want to happen inside the `ResetBA` method?

Comment: Your property naming approach is scary. Firstly, use camel case. You should manually set every property to default value. So, delete text from text fields and set switches to unselected states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to reset all of the input values to either blank or default values.

```
@IBAction func ResetBA(_ sender: Any) {
    // text fields have a "text" property
    EmailI.text = ""

    // switches have a "setOn" function
    HSSPPP.setOn(false, animated: true) // change false to true if it should be switched on
}
```

That should get you started for resetting the various fields to the starting values.

Another thing to note, it is bad practice to use capital case when naming properties in Swift. For example, you should use `emailI` instead of `EmailI`, `submitB` instead of `SubmitB`, etc.

I would also recommend reading the documentation for `UIKit` elements, as they can be very descriptive. Here is the documentation for `UITextField` for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Comment: @trent No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer helped you out it would be a good idea to accept it so others know it answered your question (hit the checkmark to the left). Good luck with your first app!